# Lightroom Tethering and EOS Utility: How to get LR to accept sub-folders in auto-import?

Tags: lightroom, tethering, eos-utility

I use EOS Utility when tethering, but all photos end up in Lightroom, and I like auto-importing into LR as I shoot.  So I use auto-import in LR, combined with a Monitor Folder provided by EOS Utility.  This combination accomplishes these goals, BUT on the condition that *everything* goes in one and only one folder, no sub-folders.  Sadly, I really like dated sub-folders, like the Import Module gives.  More specifically, here's what I tried and what doesn't work:

- If I have the EOS Utility create sub-folders via the Monitor utility (yes, it's an option in EOS Utility), and I have LR auto-import the monitored folder, LR totally ignores photos within the sub-dir.
- If I want to tweak the auto-import settings in LR to auto-magically import into dated sub-folders, that option doesn't exist, even though all those options do exist in the Import Module.
- LR's own 'tethering' option has like, one option.  It's inflexible.

Has anyone encountered this and found a workaround?

Comment: Not only is LR's own tether inflexible, its slow. I've found that it does some processing (don't know what) after 4 or so shots, and it then blocks further shots. DPP lets you shoot as fast as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Jeffrey Friedl's [Folder Watch](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/folder-watch) plugin appears to be designed to provide the functionality you want:

> This plugin attempts to fill deficiencies in Lightroom's built-in Auto-Import facilities, allowing you to auto-import images in place, in a folder or a whole tree of folders. It's likely of most use to those who shoot tethered.

It is donationware, with a $0.01 minimum donation for full functionality.

Comment: I just wanted to add that Adobe themselves say that "Auto Import does not monitor subfolders in a watched folder." (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS1FAB59DE-8867-4052-BA02-5CF6C163CD29.html).  Thanks, coneslayer, Folder Watch appears to address this (and other) deficiencies.